# instantaneous velocity

Tags: calculus

At a time $t$ seconds after it is thrown up in the air, a tomato is at a height of $f(t)=−4.9t^2+25t+9$ meters.

Find the instantaneous velocity of the tomato at $t=1.8$.

My false answer was :

$$f'(t) = -9.8t+25$$
$$t=1.8\ \text{so} f'(1.8)= 7.36$$

now to find $t_2$ and $y_2$ so I can take the average I substitute with zero and got $25$

$\text{Avg}=\frac{25-7.36}{0-1.8}=-9.8$ but it shows that the answer is wrong

Comment: It asked for instantaneous velocity. That's $f'(1.8)$.

Comment: !! Yeah, so my answer was right if I stopped and not over think about it ;/

Comment: Yes, you then went on to try to find the average velocity, which is not correctly done. The average velocity is the change in *displacement* divided by the change in time. But you already had the instantaneous velocity.

Answer (score 2):

The velocity of an object $v(t)$ is the rate of change of its displacement ($s$), in this case the height:

$$
v(t)=s'(t)=\frac{ds}{dt}
$$

So what you did first was right. The derivative of the height function will give you the instantaneous velocity function.

So the answer would be $7.36\ \text{m}/\text{s}$.